# How to show youtube embeded videos in laravel blade without using iframe

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, iframe, laravel-blade

I am using an `iframe` to show youtube videos in my webpage.

**code for videos in blade**

```
foreach($video_for_homepage as $data)
    <center>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 100%;">                
          <div class="quote-body">
            <iframe class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12" src="{{ $data->links }}" frameborder="0" style="height: 350px;" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
      </div>
    </center>
@endforeach
```

After googling, I have updated the `iframe` tag with `{!! Embed::make($data->video_link)->parseUrl()->getIframe() !!}`.

But after `inspect element` it also shows `iframe`.

As far as I know, using `iframe` for showing a video is the cause of the slowdown of a webpage.
That's why I want to show youtube videos in my webpage without using `iframe`.

How to solve this.

Anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. You can try [plyr.io](https://plyr.io/) also

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.8/plyr.css" />
<div class="plyr__video-embed" id="player">
    <video>
        <source src="{{ $videoUrl }}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.8/plyr.js"></script>
<script>
    const player = new Plyr('#player');
</script>
```

---

If you want strict with `<iframe>` then have a look at [`loading="lazy"`](https://web.dev/iframe-lazy-loading/)